# Value changes while converting Geostatistical layer to grid using ArcGIS Geostatistical Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geostatistical-analyst

I'm trying to export the GA layer (krigging interpolated temperature data) to raster. While converting, the data range is getting changed in the resultant raster (max and min) as indicated in the image.

Can someone help me out?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you read both layers as a numpy array? are the array maxes the same?

Comment: No I couldn't do that